# Flutter ListView base64 images are flashing when it displayed with Image.memory

Tags: listview, flutter, base64, flashing

Here is my [code](https://gist.github.com/abduqodirov/8c9b2ba1d3a1fdbb10e218ed38cebe2b)

I ve implemented pagination with NotificationListener as well

Comment: Please put the relevant code in the question itself as links can change and it's just easier for us.

Answer (score 5):

Add the `gaplessPlayback: true` propertie when you're rendering the images. It has to be something like that:

```
Image myImg = Image.memory(
      base64Decode(base64Image),
      height: 150,
      width: 180,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      gaplessPlayback: true, // add this
    );
```

Comment: whats about base64image in container decoration image, gaplessPlayBack not working with MemoryImage().
Please help.